# Azure Pipelines YAML: How to get rid of "Post-Build: Get Sources" step?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We are trying to get a clean YAML build going, and ran into a quirk: The build has an extra "Get Sources" step at the end, which is not in our YAML file, and can't be removed using the UI.

I created an `azure-pipelines.yml` file in the root of a new Azure Git (not GitHub) repo. A build definition was automatically created under `OurRepo/OurRepo CI` in the Builds pane on Azure DevOps.

The build works, but note the extra step at the end:

[image]

When I edit the job in Azure's UI via **Pipeline Settings**, I notice a "Get Sources" task that cannot be removed:
[image]

While this non-removable step makes sense for GUI-defined builds, I'm trying to go "pure YAML". The extra pull doesn't take long, so it's not a big deal, just annoying.

Apparently other users have this extra step in YAML builds as well: try [googling "Post-job: Get sources"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22post-job%3A%20get%20sources%22).

Am I doing something wrong, or is this just a quirk with Azure Git repos using YAML builds? ([The MS Docs tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/get-started-yaml?view=azure-devops) uses a [regular GitHub repo](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/pipelines-dotnet-core), I noticed).

**Edit:** I have also tried creating a build definition from YAML via **New Build Definition > Azure Git Repo > YAML**. The resulting page fails to detect the `azure-pipeilnes.yml` file (whether that file is empty or has a known working build definition when I committed it--tried both), so I ended up in the same place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt you can since it appears built-in to the pipeline.  Is the output of that task have similar to my post task.  Although it is labeled "Post-job Checkout".  It looks like a clean-up step to me.

```
2019-01-30T21:39:38.1940431Z ##[section]Starting: Checkout
2019-01-30T21:39:38.2032443Z ==============================================================================
2019-01-30T21:39:38.2032500Z Task         : Get sources
2019-01-30T21:39:38.2032550Z Description  : Get sources from a repository. Supports Git, TfsVC, and SVN repositories.
2019-01-30T21:39:38.2032583Z Version      : 1.0.0
2019-01-30T21:39:38.2032794Z Author       : Microsoft
2019-01-30T21:39:38.2032822Z Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=798199)
2019-01-30T21:39:38.2032852Z ==============================================================================
2019-01-30T21:39:38.5783539Z Cleaning any cached credential from repository: Sandbox (Git)
2019-01-30T21:39:38.5854582Z ##[section]Finishing: Checkout
```

Comment: As @jessehouwing mentioned, it is just "post step" for "Checkout" task that was ran earlier. Anyway, its will be great if MS will add ability to create kind of a "postfix" to the name of the post job step. "Clenup" is a good candidate, so step will be read "Post Job : Checkout (cleanup)".

Answer (score 2):

The post job step is to wipe out the downloaded source content from the hosted agent machine. There is no way that the user has control over it and it is a built-in feature.

Comment: That makes sense. The label "Get Sources" expresses the opposite intent, however.

Comment: It's the "undo" sub-step for the "Get Sources" step. Tasks can define `pre`, `execute` and `post` sub-steps. They all get the same label as the `execute` step in the UI. This is the `post` step for the task that ran the `Get Sources` to clear credentials in case another (malicious) job wants to grab them from the repo in another pipeline execution. Any steps defined in the YAML that cause pre or post steps to be loaded should show up here.

Comment: @jessehouwing Thanks, this is perfect explanation and makes sense.